# Adding a completion point for a maze in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Alright so I made a maze with JS and HTML5, and it works well and all, but now I want to add a completion point (at the end of the maze) so that when it's reached, a congratulations message pops up erasing the canvas and a link to the second maze with it.

Here is the link to it (check code by doing view source):

[Reference link](http://jacobssonstudios.netii.net/maze1.html)

controls are WASD and the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this is a quick implementation.

But you do want to optimize the code.
First of all, keyboard events should be quicker.
I mean... when you press a key, you should activate a timer that triggers the key event.
The first time you press a key, you have the key delay which takes place.You don't want that in games with arrows. Take a look into that if you want to expand the functionality and optimize gameplay.

Second you must get rid of the flickerring.
Third your alignment on the maze is not 100% good.

Here you have the solution.
But there are other ways to achieve this.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7422112/shares/canvas/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you could set up an endpoint.
Once that is matched with the moving square you completed the maze.